# Cambiar el orden al rellenar una tabla con objetos

Tags: javascript, html

Tengo el siguiente objeto, de la cual los estoy iterando para rellenarlo en una tabla. Me funciona correctamente, el detalle es que cuando añado más objetos, el ciclo `for` me pinta los objetos en este orden:

> objeto 1,objeto 2,objeto 3... objeto 1,objeto 2,objeto 3... objeto 1,objeto 2,objeto 3... así 5 veces, ya que el ciclo se repite 5 veces.

Y el resultado que quisiera es que me pinte así:

> objeto 1, objeto2, objeto3, objeto1, objeto2.

Les adjunto mi código:

```js
let obj = {
  campo: [
    {
      id: '1',
      nombre: 'Teclados',
      descripcion: 'Producto para computadoras',
      categoria: 'Tecnología',
    },
    {
      id: '2',
      nombre: 'Cubiertos',
      descripcion: 'Materiales de cocina y hogar',
      categoria: 'Cocina',
    },
    {
      id: '3',
      nombre: 'Macetas',
      descripcion: 'Objetos decorativos de casa',
      categoria: 'Decoraciones',
    },
  ],
};

function rellenarTabla(obj) {
  let tbody = document.getElementById('tablaArray');
  for (let i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
    obj.campo.forEach(c => {
      let filaNueva = '<tr>' +
          '<td><strong>' + c.id + '</strong></td>' +
          '<td>' + c.nombre + '</td>' +
          '<td>' + c.descripcion + '</td>' +
          '<td>' + c.categoria + '</td>' +
          '</tr>';
      tbody.innerHTML += filaNueva;
    });
  }
}
rellenarTabla(obj);
```

```html
<section class="bg-white">
  <div class="container pb-4 pt-0">
    <h4>Tabla con arreglo</h4>
    <div class="row py-4">
      <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 mb-lg-0">
        <table class="table table-white table-hover table-striped table-bordered">
          <thead class="tituloCrear2b">
            <tr>
              <th id="codigo">Código</th>
              <th id="nombre">Nombre</th>
              <th id="descripcion">Descripción</th>
              <th id="categoria">Categoría</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody id="tablaArray"></tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: No entiendo, sobre todo el for (let i = 1; i <= 5; i++), hay alguna logica extra?? o solo quieres colocar el array en la tabla??

Comment: Empecé con el for porque estaba trabajando con un objeto, pero cuando añadí más, me percaté del problema que iba repitiendo cada objeto en ese orden, y el resultado que espero es lo que mencionaba en mi pregunta.

Comment: Tu resultado esperado es  ```objeto 1, objeto2, objeto3, objeto1, objeto2.  ``` Es decir cuando llega al final empieza nuevamente. Donde lo importante es que siempre existan 5 elementos, aunque la lista sea menor. Favor confirma

Comment: Claro, pero cuando llegue al final, termine ahí, sería la idea...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si lo que buscas es recorrer un arreglo n veces, pero que cuando supere el largo, comience desde el principio, puedes obtener el indice de la iteración de esta forma:

```
i % obj.campo.length
```

```js
let obj = {
  campo: [
    {
      id: '1',
      nombre: 'Teclados',
      descripcion: 'Producto para computadoras',
      categoria: 'Tecnología',
    },
    {
      id: '2',
      nombre: 'Cubiertos',
      descripcion: 'Materiales de cocina y hogar',
      categoria: 'Cocina',
    },
    {
      id: '3',
      nombre: 'Macetas',
      descripcion: 'Objetos decorativos de casa',
      categoria: 'Decoraciones',
    },
  ],
};

function rellenarTabla(obj) {
  let tbody = document.getElementById('tablaArray');
  for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    let c= obj.campo[ i % obj.campo.length ];
    let filaNueva = '<tr>' +
          '<td><strong>' + c.id + '</strong></td>' +
          '<td>' + c.nombre + '</td>' +
          '<td>' + c.descripcion + '</td>' +
          '<td>' + c.categoria + '</td>' +
          '</tr>';
     tbody.innerHTML += filaNueva;
 
  }
}
rellenarTabla(obj);
```

```html
<section class="bg-white">
  <div class="container pb-4 pt-0">
    <h4>Tabla con arreglo</h4>
    <div class="row py-4">
      <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 mb-lg-0">
        <table class="table table-white table-hover table-striped table-bordered">
          <thead class="tituloCrear2b">
            <tr>
              <th id="codigo">Código</th>
              <th id="nombre">Nombre</th>
              <th id="descripcion">Descripción</th>
              <th id="categoria">Categoría</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody id="tablaArray"></tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Gracias, recién conozco sobre el `%`, me gustaría saber para qué sirve o qué es lo que hace en el ejercicio.

Comment: Es un operador, yo lo conozco como "resto entero".  Este operador divide un número y te entrega lo que "sobra".  Debes recordar las divisiones de primaria (antes que te enseñaran las fracciones), donde una división que no es exacta tenía un residuo, que generalmente se colocaba abajo, este operador te da ese número. Este operador existe en todos los lenguajes de programación que conozco

Comment: Y como se utiliza en el ejercicio?? Esto ya es un asunto más de matemáticas. Un residuo nunca puede ser mayor o igual a su divisor (por razones obvias). Entonces si yo hago n % 7 los únicos números posibles son 0,1,2,3,4,5 y 6 y así con cualquier número. El uso más común de este operador es para ver si un número es par  if(n%2==0)

Answer (score 1):

En vez de usar el operador de resto `%` uso un break para salir del while cuando se llegue al valor de `pointer`. Es una alternativa. La cantidad de entradas que quiero imprimir las paso por parametros.

```
let pointer = 0;

function rellenarTabla(obj,limit) {
  let tbody = document.getElementById('tablaArray');
  do {
    for(let i=0;i<3;i++){
      pointer++;
      tbody.innerHTML += 
      `<tr><td><strong>${obj.campo[i].id}</strong></td>
      <td>${obj.campo[i].nombre}</td>
      <td>${obj.campo[i].descripcion}</td>
      <td>${obj.campo[i].categoria}</td></tr>`;
      if(pointer===limit) break;
    }
  } while (pointer<limit)
}

rellenarTabla(obj,5);
```